# Is there any reason not to combine 2 external javascript resources into one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I'm using the colorbox plugin, which comes with this external long .js file:

http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js

and [in the demo](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example2/), there is also an inline javascript to make everything work, such as:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //Examples of how to assign the Colorbox event to elements
            $(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});
            $(".group2").colorbox({rel:'group2', transition:"fade"});
            $(".group3").colorbox({rel:'group3', transition:"none", width:"75%", height:"75%"});
            $(".group4").colorbox({rel:'group4', slideshow:true});
            $(".ajax").colorbox();
            $(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:640, innerHeight:390});
            $(".vimeo").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:500, innerHeight:409});
            $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
            $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
            $(".callbacks").colorbox({
                onOpen:function(){ alert('onOpen: colorbox is about to open'); },
                onLoad:function(){ alert('onLoad: colorbox has started to load the targeted content'); },
                onComplete:function(){ alert('onComplete: colorbox has displayed the loaded content'); },
                onCleanup:function(){ alert('onCleanup: colorbox has begun the close process'); },
                onClosed:function(){ alert('onClosed: colorbox has completely closed'); }
            });

            $('.non-retina').colorbox({rel:'group5', transition:'none'})
            $('.retina').colorbox({rel:'group5', transition:'none', retinaImage:true, retinaUrl:true});

            //Example of preserving a JavaScript event for inline calls.
            $("#click").click(function(){ 
                $('#click').css({"background-color":"#f00", "color":"#fff", "cursor":"inherit"}).text("Open this window again and this message will still be here.");
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Personally I prefer not to have such code inline, so initially I've created another external `.js` with this additional piece of code, but "google page speed tool" advised me to make it inline, since it's a very small file.

So I have tried moving this code to the long `jquery.colorbox.js` file, and it works whether I put it before or after the code. so this is basically solving both my problem and google page speed problem, and I just want to know whether there's any disadvantage for doing so?

Comment: By doing so, you broke the separation between your code and external library, making painful an external lib upgrade. Common usage is to concat and minify all your sources (no manual copy paste into on big file)

Comment: You have not to put YOUR js code into FRAMEWORK'S/PLUGIN js file anyway. + read RC answer. Also, good approach to include external libraries not from your local site, but from googleapi for example. You can't modify this file. You have to separate your js code based on its function

Comment: this sounds merely like a convenience matter, which is less important for me compared to my preference not to have it inline, and pagespeed advise to not have this little file as an external. assuming there will be no upgrade, would there be any cons? I did minified both codes.

Answer (score 1):

Not for me, but I can suggest some possibilities :

1. It may cause problem while editing
   --> This can be solved by using some comments
        --> And then this will cause the code messier
2. Some code may crash and your code success will go away from you |.|
   --> No solution - unless you know more about the code!
3. Code upgrade problem
   <-- If external code has upgrade you may have problem to know which is that code
        --> Again use comments
             --> And again messier

So these are some that I can think about!

EDIT---

Some cons:

1. You can make it more convenient to edit
   --> You can edit more than one code at once
2. You can edit some code that you wan't able to edit (external resource before)
   --> Modifying is more convenient.
3. You can make it load faster
   --> 1 file with 1000 KB is faster than 1000 files with 1 KB each.
4. It is safer
   --> You don't need to worry about external resource being deleted!!

These are my suggestions. Try to think more about it!

Comment: assuming that editing/upgrade problems do not exist in this particular case and are merely convenience matters, and since I've tested the code and it works, I guess it won't crash, I suppose there are no other obstacles then?

Comment: yes, you're right. these are just suggestions, and if this question suddenly change to a community-wiki many ideas that are possible will suddenly ___pop-pop-pop___ out.

Comment: and i see you want some cons too!

Answer (score -1):

You normally do this by involving a so called build tool. http://gruntjs.com/ is a very prominent example of such a tool.

You keep writing your code as you use to be (e.g. where you have all libs in a /lib folder and all your own code in another folder). Your own code is nicely formatted, with comments and all the things that makes editing easy. Grunt then takes all javascript files, removes the comments and minimize them (make them ugly) and puts them all in one file which you reference to in your HTML.

This is all done automatically during the build process, it's nothing you should be doing manually or even editing in such a mess.

By this way you keep all the pros (minimized file size, minimized number of HTTP requests) while keeping all the pros of editing (separated files for separated functionality, comments in your code) alive.